# Как вернуть видимость .collapse при большом экране с помощью bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Нужен список, который будет при маленьком экране скрыт под кнопкой, а при большом экране будет просто отображаться как обычный список.

В мобильной версии, для того что бы загнать список под кнопку, прописал ему класс `collapse`, и с помощью идентификатора присвоил его кнопке (список в смысле). Всё отрабатывает как надо. Как вернуть видимость списку при больших экранах?

**Пример кода:**

```
<button class="btn btn-default btn-block hidden-lg hidden-md" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#For_Business">For Business</button>
<ul class="collapse" id="For_Business">
    <li class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">For Business</li>
    <li><a href="#">Apple and Business</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Shop for Business</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: а чем вам не понравился способ, который используется в twitter bootstrap?

Comment: О каком вы способе?

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/ посмотрите на этом сайте, с помощью media queries всё делается и без добавления каких-то лишних классов

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решается данный вопрос следующим образом. Классу в `ul` надо дописать `navbar-collapse`.

```
<button class="btn btn-default btn-block visible-xs" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#For_Business">For Business</button>
<ul class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="For_Business">
    <li class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">For Business</li>
    <li><a href="#">Apple and Business</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Shop for Business</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: надуманная проблема и решение всего лишь приводит код к дефолтному коду twitter bootstrap: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default Практическая польза нулевая